# LocalHost 8545 Locked in MetaMask

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to switch to the Localhost 8545 network in Metamask.  I'm on a Windows 10 machine with a Google Chrome browser.  When I look at the settings, the "Localhost 8545" network has a gray lock on it.

[image: Network list in metamask]

When I try to switch to that network using the dropdown in the upper right corner, I can only see the "Ethereum Mainnet" and my custom network "http://localhost:7545"

[image: Metamask network selection dropdown]

When I try to manually add "Localhost 8545" by clicking on "Add Network" in the dropdown, then when I put "http://localhost:8545" in the "New RPC URL" field I get an error that says "This URL is currently used by the localhost network".

[image: This URL is currently used by the localhost network]

What should I do to switch to the Localhost 8545 network in Metamask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the same problem. you have to got to settings, advanced options, then toggle show test networks