# Metamask won't switch to Localhost 8545

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I'm trying to get Metamask to connect to my "Localhost 8545" network.  I've already unlocked the Test networks following the information provided in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113935/localhost-8545-locked-in-metamask/113986#113986)

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and I have a local Ethereum network running.  I started the network with this command:

```
geth --networkid 1337 --mine --miner.threads 1 --datadir "." --nodiscover --http --http.port "8545" --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Based on the network definition in Metamask, my local network should be a network at http://localhost:8545 with ChainID 1337.  See the text excerpt from the local network startup below showing that it's running on 127.0.0.1 (localnetwork) and on ChainID 1337:

```
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.309] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.316] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.323] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.329] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\Users\username\project_name\private\geth\chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=8192
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.398] Opened ancient database                  database=C:\Users\username\project_name\private\geth\chaindata\ancient readonly=false
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.405] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Berlin: <nil>, London: <nil>, Arrow Glacier: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.446] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\Users\username\project_name\private\geth\ethash count=3
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.465] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Ethash count=2
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.470] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1337 dbversion=8
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.512] Loaded most recent local header          number=31 hash=6a503a..c17ba6 td=16,332,535 age=7m41s
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.519] Loaded most recent local full block      number=31 hash=6a503a..c17ba6 td=16,332,535 age=7m41s
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.547] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=31 hash=6a503a..c17ba6 td=16,332,535 age=7m41s
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.559] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.592] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
WARN [11-22|11:58:44.610] Switch sync mode from fast sync to full sync
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.629] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.633] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.12-stable-6c4dc6c3/windows-amd64/go1.17.2
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.699] New local node record                    seq=1,637,606,845,862 id=8e46c88443901532 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=0 tcp=30303
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.700] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.708] Started P2P networking                   self="enode://0cb228df47ffed3cfebddac8a84836d427467bb1ae9cab68c324756f1875232947d5a2e91a7f19216ed912847c4830321582909c9357b1dd2a98aeb06c537896@127.0.0.1:30303?discport=0"
INFO [11-22|11:58:44.713] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
```

When I try to switch to this network in Metamask, it doesn't work and just flips back to whatever network I was on before I tried to switch to "Localnetwork 8545".

[image: clicking on Localnetwork 8545]

After clicking on "Localnetwork 8545" (red arrow in image) it just goes back the "Ethereum Mainnet":

[image: Switches back to Ethereum Mainnet]

What do I need to do differently, so I can connect "Localhost 8545" in Metamask with the local network I'm running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix this I installed version 10.6.2 manually and the localhost network option began working again.
It seem to be a problem with version 10.6.1

The link to download version 10.6.2
URL: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases/tag/v10.6.2
[1] download the metamask-chrome-10.6.2.zip
[2] unzip the file
[3] go to chrome settings => extensions => developer mode on
[4] Load unpacked

See how to wiki => https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489471-How-to-install-MetaMask-manually

I hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Seems like it must have been a bug in version 10.6.1.  Thanks Eric. M!

Answer (score 1):

I created a new network with 127.0.0.1:8545 , and I switch it finally worked ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem! I am running my node server properly, but for some reason it will not let me connect to the localhost! I have spent all day trying to figure this out, and I am at a loss.

EDIT:

So I was able to solve the issue. Do not try to connect to the default localhost on metamask. Change your chainId in your hardhat.config.js file
to something other than 1331 then start your node server. Right AFTER  you start your node server, create a new network on metamask. Your RPC URL will be the URL that your node server gives you. Your chainId will be the new chainId that you inputted. when you create your new server it should work.